# Sort on anonymous type in DBQuery

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I'm struggling with an issue I have to be able to retrieve data from the database efficiently.

I'm using EF 4.3/c#.

Here's my EF logic that pulls back data:

```
IEnumerable<Offer> GetHotOffers()
{
    using (var uow = new UnitOfWork(Connection.Products))
    {
        var r = new Repository<Offer>(uow.Context);

        return r.Find(o =>
            o.OfferPopularity != null &&
            o.OfferPopularity.TotalVotes > 5 && o.OfferPopularity.PctUpvotes >= 55)
            .Include(o => o.OfferPopularity)
            .ToList() <= this needs to be removed
            .OrderByDescending(o => ** an in memory method **)
            .Take(20)
            .ToList();
    }
}
```

The `Find()` method is simple a repository wrapper - it returns `DBQuery<T>`.

In the database I have 2 pieces of data:

- PctUpvotes - a decimal figure showing the % up upvotes (as opposed to
  downvotes). Total of both = 100.
- TotalVotes - the total number of votes cast.

As you can see from the query, I'm able to narrow down the selection somewhat in the `Find()` method, which means its done at the database.

However, I want to order the list using data that is not readily available, but can be assumed. I decided not to put it into a computed field because it was tieing changable logic into the database.

Here's the logic I need to incorporate, it's abit like a traffic light system:

- Min PctUpvotes 55%,  Min TotalVotes: 5 = level 1
- Min PctUpvotes 60%,  Min TotalVotes: 10 = level 2
- Min PctUpvotes 65%,  Min TotalVotes: 15 = level 3
- Min PctUpvotes 70%,  Min TotalVotes: 20 = level 4

So, once I've made the base selection, need to order them by level (descending) then PctUpvotes (descending).

I could do this once the query has been converted to a list, simply by calling a method in the linq logic after the `ToList()`, something like this:

```
public static int AdjVotes(int votes, decimal pctUpvotes)
{
    if (votes >= 20 && pctUpvotes > 70) return 4;
    if (votes >= 15 && pctUpvotes > 65) return 3;
    if (votes >= 10 && pctUpvotes > 60) return 2;

    return 1;
}
```

However, it's done in memory, not at the database.

The question I have is: can the logic above be incorporate into the DBQuery logic so that I don't have to call `ToList()` twice, and have the whole thing run against the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Operator `(bool)?(trueValue):(falseValue)` is compiled to native db query; it will look a little messy though:

```
return r.Find(o =>
  o.OfferPopularity != null &&
  o.OfferPopularity.TotalVotes > 5 && o.OfferPopularity.PctUpvotes >= 55)
  .Include(o => o.OfferPopularity)
  .OrderByDescending(o =>
    (o.OfferPopularity.TotalVotes >= 20 && o.OfferPopularity.TotalVotes > 70 ? 4 :
      (o.OfferPopularity.TotalVotes >= 15 && o.OfferPopularity.TotalVotes > 65 ? 3 :
        (o.OfferPopularity.TotalVotes >= 10 && o.OfferPopularity.TotalVotes > 60 ? 2 : 1))))
  .Take(20)
  .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks Ondrej - I don't mind a little messy in this instance as it means not having to sort 1000 rows in memory. I think its a reasonable compromise.